# Using 2 different email providers under 1 domain

Tags: email, google-workspace

I know this may have been asked but I can't get a concrete answer online.

We have a small company that is currently using Dreamhost Webmail services for its email accounts. Our domain is hosted on wix.com. Lets say @czech.biz

However, we are having difficulties using these said accounts with different gmail products, most importantly google calendar invites are not syncing to user's google calendar under a different gmail address.

Now a proposal is on the table to move 2-3 email addresses of the executive team to Google workspace to go around this problem. Is there a way to use google workspace for only those 3 email addresses under the same @czech.biz and keep different users using their email addresses in Dreamhost under the same domain?

The goal is not to have users accessing both email providers for the same address just to be clear..

Thank you in advance for any assistance or feedback you can provide.

Comment: You can forward selected addresses to Gmail, but then they will obviously need to use Gmail to read their messages. If Dreamhost has facilities to forward a copy, you could deliver to both places.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

Probably the easiest way is to set each of the 3 email addresses to forward all the email received to Google Workspace and set each of the accounts to use the SMTP servers of Dreamhost instead of the Gmail servers.

Besides the interoperability between Google apps (Gmail, Calendar, etc.) you should be aware about things like SPF checks.

All the instructions and other options are options are documented in [Google Workspace Admin Help](https://support.google.com/a) (GWAH), even they have documentation for many of the general reference concepts required for taking choosing between the options that they mention.

Examples of help articles from GWAH:

- [Email routing and delivery options for Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2685650?hl=en)
- [Deliver email to multiple inboxes with dual delivery](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9228551?hl=en)

  This article include the instructions corresponding to the option mentioned above, more specifically in the section "Option 2: Dual delivery—Legacy server as primary server". IMO, it's too large to be quoted here. Briefly, you will have to add DNS records for a temporary domain, use this domain to set the primary email boxes to forward all the incoming emails to Gmail servers among other things.

Personally I lead an initiative to do this for a Mexican university around 2010. We started with my account and gradually included more and more users. Nowadays the IT area officially supports using Outlook on the Web and Gmail (Workspace), they even implemented SSO. I only had to update my primary mailbox configuration when the University changed the primary email system more than 8 years ago. It's still working.

Related

- [Google Apps Mail & Remote webserver: Email goes to spam even with DKIM & SPF](https://superuser.com/q/1049397/152004)
- [Is there any way of using Google mail "internally" whilst on same domain as O365?](https://superuser.com/q/1168726/152004)